# "Про Шария" - где ставить ударение?

Tags: ударение

Is there any rule in Russian on how to put stresses on last names in conjugation, precisely in Accusative?

What's the right way of saying: про Ш**а**рия or про Шари**я**?

It looked logical to me that since "-я" is merely an ending of Accusative and is not found in the base form (Nominative) "Шарий", the stress should remain on the letter, which is not an ending ("Камар**о**в" - "про Камар**о**ва", "Г**у**сев" - "про Г**у**сева", "П**у**тин" - "про П**у**тина", "Жегл**о**в" - "про Жегл**о**ва"); however, the owner of this last name has recently claimed that the right way is "про Шари**я**" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsSERuc_tnc&t=118s), which surprised me quite a lot.

Comment: I'm sure there is no rule. It's all sort of "conventional". I mean you say it, like most people around you say it (unless you for some reason want to do otherwise). For the last names the main factor to affect the pronunciation is how a name's owner pronounce it himself, generally. As for Шарий, most people, whom I know, say Шари*я*.

Comment: at the same time Б**е**рия — Б**е**рии, Гамсах**у**рдия — Гамсах**у**рдии

Comment: @user907860 - Can you come up with any example in Russian when the stress would slide to the ending in Accusative?

Comment: examples are numerous with (at least) sort of "Ukrainian" last names (to which "Шарий" belongs). Кул**и**к — Кулик**а**, Кролев**е**ц — Кролевц**а**. But, for instance, Змеевец we usually do not conjugate, so Змеев**е**ц — Змеев**е**ц (in the accusative). This is a matter of convention and personal preference in many cases, I wouldn't be surprised, if I met a man, who pronounced his last name as: Змеевц**а**

Comment: Names come from different languages - and so rules of respective languages apply. In English it is yet worse - names coming from German, French, Spanish - and while using same letters their sound spelling patterns are radically different.

Comment: There is a whole bunch of surnames of Ukrainian origin ending in stressed *-ий*: *Шарий, Топчий, Повалий, Кучмий* etc., which decline according to the nominal rather than adjectival paradigm when masculine and don't decline at all when feminine. Apparently they all use Ukrainian agentive suffix *-iй*, as in *водiй* "driver", *носiй* "carrier, medium" etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are plenty of Russian names and common words where the stress shifts to the ending in Accusative:

- Карамзи́н – Карамзина́
- Зализня́к – Зализняка́
- Гришкове́ц – Гришковца́ (with the fleeting vowel *-e-* dropped)
- кузне́ц – кузнеца́ ('blacksmith')
- врач – врача́ ('doctor')
- бегу́н – бегуна́ ('runner')
- коро́ль – короля́ ('king')
- кома́р – комара́ ('mosquito')
- лев – льва́ ('lion', with the fleeting *-е-* dropped and *-ь-* inserted)
- орёл – орла́ ('eagle', with the fleeting *-ё-* dropped)
- Христо́с – Христа́ (with *-ос* dropped which is a feature unique to this word).

Note that all words above have stress on the last syllable in Nominative.

> What's the right way of saying: про Ш**а**рия or про Шари**я**?

Apparently, the guy prefers to be called Шар**и**й. In this case the rules of Russian stress do allow a shift to the ending (буга́й - бугая́). And yes, there are rules in the placement of Russian stress, it is not completely random: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H3ynNOoGiA

Comment: Sorry, would you remove "стола́" from your list, since it's not Accusative?

Comment: Done. My mistake, thanks. Although the same principle holds for other cases as well: стол - стола́, столу́, столо́м, столе́.

Comment: with лев I think initially in Pra-Slavic there were short vowels, like in Bulgarian. When the short vowels got extinct in Russian in Nominative that vowel was the only and thus got extended to full vowel, in other cases the full vowel was added with endings and thus the short vowel got removed. Though wiki scoffs at this my hypothesis - see 3.6 at  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a personal name often retains its initial stress position. A stress position depends largely on a 'country of origin' of a personal name.

The rule works also with loan words, e.g. a lot of personal Latin or latinized names retain their initial position of a stressed syllable, which, for most -***ий***-ending two-syllable words of anciet origin, is a first one:

***Кáссий - о Кáссии / про Кáссия***

***Дáрий - о Дáрии / про Дáрия***

***Клáвдий - о Клáвдии / про Клáвдия***

However, the surname ***[Шарий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#.D0.A1.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8C.D1.8F_.D0.BE_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.85)*** is a Ukrainian one with a stressed ***и*** and is thus close to Russian adjectives of the types ***вторóй, малóй, литóй, святóй***, etc.

(The shift from o to i seems to be typical archaic trait for Ukrainian as a proof for Balto-German-Slavic proto-unity).

Besides, an owner of a name should be given a priority in defining its stress.

The correct form is therefore ***про ШарИя***.

Comment: It completely depends on stress position in the name of a _particular person_. Here's a famous enough athlete Валерий Ш**а**рий: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87

Comment: _Шарий_ is not close to adjectives. It would be if its Accusative were _Шарого_, but it's not. For both Anatoly and Valery it's _Шария_.

Comment: Cf. Belorussian Шарый. An etymological resourse gives for the Ukrainian surname an explanation as derived from 'ширiй' = 'gray'.

Comment: "It would be if its Accusative were" - no. When the word is "cloned" into another class, its flexing patterns often change accordingly. Compare любовь/Любовь -> любви/Любови